# Названия пунктов меню стороннего приложения

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

Как, зная HWND окна (и самого меню), получить все названия пунктов меню стороннего приложения (C#)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
IntPtr HMENU = GetMenu((IntPtr)0x90D86); //?
```

Comment: Вам нужно [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Придётся прочитать довольно много.

Answer (score 1):

Hwnd указываете при вызове метода AutomationElement.FromHandle,
а дальше находите TreeScope.Children.

Программа позволяет выводить все элементы меню, находящиеся под мышью.  Например, если стать мышью на TEST, то выводятся элементы меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код программы:

```
// Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51204
#r "System.Windows.Forms"
#r "WindowsBase"
#r "UIAutomationTypes"
#r "UIAutomationClient"

using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static string[] menuItems(int x, int y) {
    var ae = AutomationElement.FromPoint(new System.Windows.Point(x, y));
    return (ae.Current.ClassName != "MenuItem")
        ? new string[0]
        : ae.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)
            .OfType<AutomationElement>().Select(e => e.Current.Name).ToArray();
}

var frm = new Form() { Width = 300, Height = 180, TopMost = true };
var rtb = new RichTextBox() { Parent = frm, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
new Timer() { Interval = 500, Enabled = true }
      .Tick += (s, e) => {
          var pos = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
          rtb.Text = String.Join("\n", menuItems(pos.X, pos.Y));
      };
frm.ShowDialog();
```

---

Для компиляции кода и запуска приложения, например, в Visual Studio Community 2015 надо открыть `View - Other Windows - C# Interactive`, скопировать в него код и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Visual Studio Community 2015 - бесплатная версия, ее можно скачать [тут](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146).

Comment: +1. Нo вывод здесь по идее лишний, интересен только модельный код (функция `menuItems`).