# Как кликнуть на нужной иконке в трее программно?

Tags: c#, winapi

Более-менее знаком с WinApi, работаю посредством c#. Через WinSpector смотрю данные окон, кнопок и т.д. Необходимо произвести клик правой кнопкой мыши на определенной иконке в трее и затем кликнуть на определенный элемент в контекстном меню, которое появится. 
Отображаемые элементы в трее определяются одним объектом класса ToolbarWindow32, но как обратиться к определенным элементам - не знаю. Так же интересует, как можно узнать данные из всплывающего окна(Baloon message).

Comment: WinAPI обязательно использовать? есть Automation

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы кликнуть на иконке в трее можно использовать Automation.
Например, если hwnd у иконки в трее равен 65696, то пишем так

```
#r "UIAutomationTypes"
#r "UIAutomationClient"

using System.Windows.Automation;
var a = AutomationElement.FromHandle((IntPtr) 65696);
var p = a.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
p.Invoke();
```

Элементы меню можно получить с помощью [menuItems](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481852/196972).
Hwnd можно получить с помощь [HWndSpy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481836/).
Пример right click - см. [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8930781).

Comment: Я в этой сфере еще новичок и у меня мало что получилось. Хендл я зачастую беру посредством Title или ClassName в самом коде. Их беру, или из Winspector, или из своего приложения, которое выполняет практически те же функции, что и HWndSpy. 
Как мне получить хендл иконки, если трей идет одним контейнером(объектом?). menuitems у меня работает некорректно, даже копипастом(не отображает ничего).

Comment: Разобрался с menuitem, но там идет отображение только элементов меню, а мне нужно контекстное меню. И еще, возможно ли получить текст из всплывающего сообщения определенного приложения?

Comment: _"Как мне получить хендл иконки, если трей идет одним контейнером(объектом?)"_ -- в [HWndSpy](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481837/196972) есть функцию WindowFromPoint. есть указать координаты иконки, то получите hwnd

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко _"возможно ли получить текст из всплывающего сообщения определенного приложения"_ -- возможно. надо  перехватывать создание окон. это делается с помощью событий automation или глобальных хуков. но это непросто.

Comment: "в HWndSpy есть функцию WindowFromPoint" - я эту функцию и использую, вот только, повторюсь еще раз, трей выступает одним окном с классом ToolbarWindow32. А всплывающее окно - tooltips_class32. Как мне из этих окон вытянуть информацию, в этом и вопрос состоит. Перехватить это одно, проблема достать текст и координаты определенной иконки.

Comment: _"трей выступает одним окном"_ -- в какой версии Windows? у меня Windows 10 - у иконок в трее свои hwnd. проверял для: сеть, уведомления, клавиатура.

Comment: Windows 7 и приложение разрабатывается именно для этой операционной системы. Если бы так просто можно было получить хендл, я бы не задавал вопрос. :)

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко _"Windows 7 и приложение разрабатывается именно для этой операционной системы."_ -- см. [A tool to order the window buttons in your taskbar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10497/A-tool-to-order-the-window-buttons-in-your-taskbar)

Comment: к сожалению, это приложение не подходит для моей операционной системы.

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко _"это приложение не подходит для моей операционной системы"_ --  а функция User32.SendMessage(hToolbar,TB.GETBUTTON...) у вас не работает?

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко попробуйте получить AutomationElement по x и y, так: `var a = AutomationElement.FromPoint(new Point(x, y));`